# How to get Java for Debian/Arm

Tags: debian, java

I need to run a Java application in a box running Debian Sarge with an armv4 processor. How can I do it? I can't find any java runtime for that system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On my searches for exactly the same thing I came across the following possible solutions:

1. [JamVM](http://jamvm.sourceforge.net/), a very lightweight JVM without JIT compiler which of course makes it slower but also much less memory hungry.  It implements Java 2 (aka 1.4) I did some tests with JamVM on my Linksys "Slug", a 266MHz PXA420 device and performance was surprisingly good.
2. [CacaoVM](http://www.cacaovm.org/), which has a JIT compiler and implements Java 5.

Although there are other JVM projects, I focused on these two because of their specific properties (like JamVM's tiny size), relative ease of implementation (mind you, I don't say simple!) and the fact that both project are quite active.

Hope this helps.